# Список потомков в дереве

Tags: javascript

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for( let i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ){

  try{
     if(li[i].lastElementChild.querySelectorAll('li').length) {
        let descendantsCount = li[i].lastElementChild.querySelectorAll('li').length;
        li[i].firstChild.data += descendantsCount
         console.log( descendantsCount )
     }
  } catch(e){
      
    if( e.name == 'TypeError') continue

  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Животные
      <ul>
        <li>Млекопитающие
          <ul>
            <li>Коровы</li>
            <li>Ослы</li>
            <li>Собаки</li>
            <li>Тигры</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Другие
          <ul>
            <li>Змеи</li>
            <li>Птицы</li>
            <li>Ящерицы</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Рыбы
      <ul>
        <li>Аквариумные
          <ul>
            <li>Гуппи</li>
            <li>Скалярии</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Морские
          <ul>
            <li>Морская форель</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

1. Подскажите как можно код записать короче ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => 
  item.children.length? console.log(item.querySelectorAll('li').length) : 0);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Животные
      <ul>
        <li>Млекопитающие
          <ul>
            <li>Коровы</li>
            <li>Ослы</li>
            <li>Собаки</li>
            <li>Тигры</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Другие
          <ul>
            <li>Змеи</li>
            <li>Птицы</li>
            <li>Ящерицы</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Рыбы
      <ul>
        <li>Аквариумные
          <ul>
            <li>Гуппи</li>
            <li>Скалярии</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Морские
          <ul>
            <li>Морская форель</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: скажите мой вариант плохой ?

Comment: @user354190 нормальный

Comment: спасибо (какой-то текст )